# Are matroids really a generalization of independence in vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, matroids

The axioms of matroids are (Wikipedia):

---

A finite matroid $M$ is a pair $(E,\mathcal{I})$, where $E$ is a finite set (called the ground set) and $\mathcal{I}$ is a family of subsets of $E$ (called the independent sets) with the following properties:

1. $\mathcal{I}\neq\emptyset$
2. $A'\subseteq A\in\mathcal{I}\Rightarrow
       A'\in\mathcal{I}$
3. $A,B\in\mathcal{I}\wedge |A|>|B|\Rightarrow  \exists x\in
       A:B\cup\{x\}\in\mathcal{I}\wedge |B\cup\{x\}|>|B|$

---

In linear algebra any vector $v\neq 0$ is independent, but an element of $E$ doesn't have to occur in any set in $\mathcal{I}$ according to the axioms.

It seems to me that generator sets for finitely generated modules over some ring would be a more general representation of the matroids? Where torsion elements corresponds to $v$ above.

Comment: Why did you assume $v \neq 0$ right away? $v=0$ is precisely an example of such an element of $E$ that doesn't occur in any independent set.

Comment: Besides, if $M$ is a finitely generated module over some ring $R$, its generator sets in general do *not* form a matroid. Axiom (2) doesn't hold: if a set generates $M$, it can have a subset that doesn't generate $M$.

Comment: Yes, is was a mismatch. So any matroid is represented by some vectors in a linear space? And generators of modules is something else?

Comment: @Dan: thanks! I will struggle forth with matroids.

Comment: No, not every matroid is represented by some vectors of a linear space. [Not every matroid is linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid_representation#Characterization_of_linear_matroids). But the converse holds: any finite subset of a vector space not contained in $\{0\}$ is a matroid (w.r.t. linear independence).

Comment: On second thought, there's no need to require that the set isn't contained in $\{0\}$. Any finite subset of a vector space is a matroid.

Comment: @Lehs: Read the first few pages in https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_09/papers/Will.pdf

Comment: @Moritz. Thanks, I'll look at it and maybe include matroids in my system for computational mathematics http://forthmath.blogspot.se/